# Intervalo de datas C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma tabela no banco chamada Cota, essa cota tem duas colunas uma para data_inicio e data_fim, até aqui tudo bem, agora eu tenho outra tabela chamada Ordem que tambem tem data_inicio e data_fim, essas tabelas são relacionadas 1 para N, uma cota pode ter N Ordens, criei uma validação para não deixar o usuario criar uma ordem que não seja maior ou menor que a data da cota cadastrada, toda ordem precisa estar dentro do intervalo cadastrado na Cota, meu problema é que também não posso deixar o usuario cadastrar uma ordem que entre dentro do intervalo de otra ordem, exemplo:

Data da Cota: data_inicio 10/08/2017 e data_fim: 20/08/2017

1: Data da Ordem: data_inicio 11/08/2017 e data_fim: 15/08/2017

Aqui esta o problema:

2: Data da Ordem: data_inicio 13/08/2017 e data_fim: 17/08/2017

A data_inicio 13/08/2017 dessa ultima ordem entrou no intervalo da 1 Ordem: data_inicio 11/08/2017 e data_fim: 15/08/2017 isso não pode ocorrer.

Existe algum método ou alguma solução para isso, sugesão de melhoria ?
Aqui está o metodo com algumas validações que fiz.

```
 public void ValidarDataDaOrdem(decimal idCota, DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataFim)
    {
        var cota = Context.Cota.Include("Ordem").Where(e => e.IdCota == idCota).FirstOrDefault();
        var ordens = cota.Ordem.ToList();

        if (dataInicio < cota.dataInicioCota)
        {
            throw new InfoException("Data Inico tem que ser maior que a data inicio da cota");
        }
        if (dataFim > cota.DataFimCota)
        {
            throw new InfoException("Data Final tem que ser menor que a data final da cota");
        }

        foreach (var item in ordens)
        {
            if (item.DataInicioOrdem == dataInicio && item.DataInicioOrdem == DataFim)
            {
                throw new InfoException("Ja existe solicitação cadastrada para esse periodo");
            }
            if (item.DataInicioOrdem == dataInicio || item.DataInicioOrdem == DataFim)
            {
                throw new InfoException("Ja existe solicitação cadastrada para essa data");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu recomendo substituir esse trecho:

```
foreach (var item in ordens)
{
    if (item.DataInicioOrdem == dataInicio && item.DataInicioOrdem == DataFim)
    {
        throw new InfoException("Ja existe solicitação cadastrada para esse periodo");
    }
    if (item.DataInicioOrdem == dataInicio || item.DataInicioOrdem == DataFim)
    {
        throw new InfoException("Ja existe solicitação cadastrada para essa data");
    }
}
```

Por:

```
var ordemEmChoque = ordens.FirstOrDefault(o =>
    (o.DataInicioOrdem <= dataInicio && o.DataFimOrdem >= dataInicio) ||
    (o.DataInicioOrdem <= dataFim && o.DataFimOrdem >= dataInicio)
);
if (ordemEmChoque != null) {
    throw new InfoException("Já existe uma solicitação cadastrada com choques " +
        "de data para a nova solicitação. A solicitação já existente é a de número" + foo);
}
```

Onde `foo` é uma identidade ou código que identifique uma ordem já existente.

Answer (score 1):

Imagino que você esteja validando as datas de entrada no client, ainda assim, sendo uma informação condicional da funcionalidade, deveria validar novamente no server.

Não testei efetivamente, mas creio que algo assim pode ajudá-lo:

```
public void ValidarDataDaOrdem(decimal idCota, DateTime dataInicio, DateTime dataFim)
{
    var cota = Context.Cota.Include("Ordem").Where(e => e.IdCota == idCota).FirstOrDefault();

    if(dataInicio > dataFim || dataInicio < cota.DataInicio  || dataInicio > cota.DataFim || dataFinal > cota.DataFinal || dataFinal < cota.DataInicio)
        throw new InfoException($"Datas informadas fora do intervalo permitido [De: {cota.DataInicio} à {cota.DataFim}");

    if(cota.Ordem.Where(item=> dataInicio >= item.dataInicioOrdem && dataInicio <= item.dataFimOrdem).count() > 0)
        throw new InfoException("Já existe uma solicitação cadastrada para este período.");
}
```

Você poderia pesquisar por linq e lambda pra utilizar melhor as questões de filtros e etc. Melhorar as queries de uma maneira geral. É muito simples e produtivo. (=